# Android setVideoEncodingBitRate() is not defined in package MediaRecorder

Tags: android, media, video-recording, mediarecorder

I am trying to the change the encoding bit rate of the video recording on Android using `MediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(int)`.

I looked in the android documentation and it states this method to set/change the bit rate but when I try to use this method I am getting `setVideoEncodingBitrRate(int)` is not defined in package `MediaRecorder`.

Why it is so?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you should check that which API version you are using

`setVideoEncodingBitRate()` just come on API v8 or Android 2.1

If you use version less than that it would not be available :D

---

Also you could use it like this

```
webCamRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
if (target_holder == null)
    return;
webCamRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(target_holder.getSurface());
webCamRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
webCamRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
webCamRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
webCamRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(196608);
webCamRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
webCamRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
webCamRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(15000000);
webCamRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
webCamRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
webCamRecorder.setOutputFile("your location to save");
```

Comment: Then you should try to follow the step of making MediaRecorder as my example :]

Answer (score 0):

`setVideoEncodingBitRate` is an instance method, seems that you are trying to call it as a static method (`MediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(int)`), instead, call it from the MediaRecorder object.

```
MediaRecorder mr = new MediaRecorder();
mr.setVideoEncodingBitRate(someint);
```

Also, did you import `android.media.MediaRecorder` ?

Comment: I am creating instance of it and setting the parameters with the object only. Also I imported `android.media.MediaRecorder`